# My php & mysqli script is returning with zero rows in database even though there is a row

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am semi-new to PHP and MySQL so I was using this tutorial video to set up the forgotten password system for their previous tutorial on a login system (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wUkKCMEYj9M, timestamp to the part I am working on is 1:05:46). 
Everything was working fine until I got to the part where we had to create the new password and anytime I submit the new password, it receives an error essentially saying that there are no rows in the database, or at least I believe that is what the error is. (Error Message: You need to re-submit your request (1)) Below I have given my code (The file for the database connector is accurately named dbc.inc.php, I messed it up when originally naming it so I just apply the different name to my scripts) and if you see what it is, I will be very grateful. Thanks!

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["reset-password-submit"])) {

    $selector = $_POST["selector"];
    $validator = $_POST["validator"];
    $password = $_POST["pwd"];
    $passwordRepeat = $_POST["pwd-repeat"];

    if(empty($password) || empty($passwordRepeat)) {
        header("Location: ../create-new-password.php?newpwd=empty&selector=". $selector . "&validator=" . $validator);
        exit();
    } 
    else if ($password != $passwordRepeat){
        header("Location: ../create-new-password.php?newpwd=pwdnotsame&selector=". $selector . "&validator=" . $validator);
        exit();
    }

    $currentDate = date("U");

    require 'dbc.inc.php';

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM pwdReset WHERE pwdResetSelector=? AND pwdResetExpires >= ?";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        echo "There was an error. (1)";
        exit();
    } 
    else {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $selector, $currentDate);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
        if(!$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "You need to re-submit your reset request. (1)";
            exit();
        } 
        else 
        {
            $tokenBin = hex2bin($validator);
            $tokenCheck = password_verify($tokenBin, $row["pwdResetToken"]);

            if($tokenCheck == false) 
            {
                echo "You need to re-submit your reset request. (2)";
                exit();
            } 
            else if ($tokenCheck == true) 
            {
                $tokenEmail = $row['pwdResetEmail'];

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE emailUsers=?;";
                $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
                    echo "There was an error. (2)";
                    exit();
                } 
                else {
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $tokenEmail);
                    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

                    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
                    if(!$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                        echo "There was an error. (3)";
                        exit();
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        $sql = "UPDATE users SET pwdUsers=? WHERE emailUsers=?";
                        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                        if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
                            echo "There was an error. (4)";
                            exit();
                        } 
                        else {
                            $newPwdHash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $newPwdHash, $tokenEmail);
                            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt); 

                            $sql = "DELETE FROM pwdReset WHERE pwdResetEmails=?";
                            $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                            if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
                                echo "There was an error. (5)";
                                exit();
                            } 
                            else {
                                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $tokenEmail);
                                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt); 
                                header("Location: ../signup.php?newpwd=passwordupdated");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
else {
    header("Location: ../index.php");
}
```

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing an access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Any modern [development framework](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in, and there are [authentication libraries](http://phprbac.net/) you can use. Unless this is purely for academic purposes, **do not use this code in production**.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files. They're also patched and maintained, unlike YouTube videos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong. In the page the user would input their new password on also stores the selector and token, both of which I had misspelled value on. The script above works fine with a minor tweak to the bottom part.

The new hash part should be:

```
$newPwdHash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $newPwdHash, $tokenEmail);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt); 

$sql = "DELETE FROM pwdReset WHERE pwdResetEmail=?";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
     echo "There was an error 5";
     exit();
} else {
      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $tokenEmail);
      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
      header("Location: ../signup.php?newpwd=passwordupdated");
}
```

Not what it was originally above.